# Certain characters formatted with ### seem messed up under 100% zoom

Tags: bug, design

I recently came across [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110745/multiple-fizzbuzz-with-input-from-file/110787#110787) and noticed some issues with the heading text.

For instance, the first one (with `###`):

> #### main(arg)

That third letter is supposed to be an 'i', but it looks like an 'l'.  I first made sure it was correct in that post, and it was.

However, it seems okay with `#`, `##`, and `**` (respectively):

> ## main(args)
>
> ### main(args)
>
> **main(args)**

(The 'i' is still a little fuzzy with `##`, but it can still be seen.)

This is observed under 100% zoom in Chrome.  Increasing it seems to make it a little better, whereas decreasing it helps more.

Comment: On 100% zoom in Firefox it looks just fine. Sure, the distance between the dot and the stick could be better, but it's clear enough to read.

Comment: @mast that's strange, I get the same as Jamal... 100% zoom on Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE. Might be to do with screen resolution?

Comment: Any news on this? It makes otherwise great answers like [this one](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/127039/34163) from h.j.k. extremely annoying to read.

Comment: Absolutely no issue on FF.  Also, this won't be a bug with SE, but either a bug in the way either the browser or Chrome renders text on that screen resolution and scale.

Comment: Is this question still current?

Comment: @Mast: Yes, I still see this issue.

Comment: @Jamal looks like this might be fixed, I will leave it to you to verify that it is fixed for you as well and retag.